# Keep lowercase in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, french

I have a little issue, my bibliography (using Biblatex, biber) is written in upper case
while I did note specified anything (I think), and I'm not
happy with this.

Here is a little example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chem-angew,
    doi = false,
    url = false,
    sorting = none,
]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.8\itemsep}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{myArticle,
author={Author},
title={Title},
journal={Journal},
year={2000},
volume={1}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}

Let's cite this : \cite{myArticle}.

\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

And I obtain "AUTHOR" with the A bigger than the other letters, but still everything in capitalized letters.
I saw people have similar issue, but usually this is the opposite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Family names in small caps are a default of the French localisation module. You can turn that behaviour off with

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```

The `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}` is necessary to make sure to overwrite the settings of the localisation module, which would otherwise take precedence over the settings in the preamble.

With the restored `\mkbibnamefamily` it is also possible to change the definition of `\mkbibnamefamily` in the preamble directly.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to mean  the author name is typeset in small caps. This is the default if the main language is French.

If you really don't want it, you may add these lines to your preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\protected\def\mkbibnamefamily#1{%
\textnohyphenation{#1}}}%
```

[image]

Comment: This command also works, although I accepted the one from moewe.