# Conflict using french babel resulting in bibliography refs appearing in smallcaps

Tags: biblatex, babel, small-caps, french

I wanted to re-run my thesis and while I changed nothing (nor the file format, the bib file or anything), all my references in the text now appear in smallcaps. I suspect there is a conflict with the french babel package because when I remove

```
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
```

my biblio references appear in normal caps. But then all my chapter and section names are not in french anymore (abstract, listofigures, etc.). Any idea on how to solve this conflict?

here's the mwe

```
\pdfobjcompresslevel 0
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}  % default square logo 

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}% pour avoir les titres en français (table des matières, etc.)
 %%% UTILS %%%
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,firstinits=true,style=authoryear,useprefix=true,url=false,doi=false,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{#1}}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}% quelques options + compatibilité    natbib 
\usepackage{slbiblatex} % personalized package for biblio but does not have babel options
\addbibresource{BiblioThese.bib} % fichier bib

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad#1.}
\makeatother
\clearpage
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
%%%%%  latex en-tête %%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}


 %%%% nom des figures
 \AtBeginDocument{%
 \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure} % change figure appearance
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Table} % change figure appearance
  }

  %load any additional packages
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}

   \usepackage{enumitem}% package pour enumérer en roman

   \newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
   \begin{document}
   \renewcommand{\bibname}{R\'ef\'erences bibliographiques}
  \baselineskip=24pt plus1pt

  %set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

 \include{dedication}       
 \include{acknowlegements}   
 \include{abstract}          
 \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
 \include{abstract-eng}          % include the abstract
 \begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
 \tableofcontents       
 \listoffigures         
 \listoftables          
 \include{Listofpapers}
 \end{romanpages}            % end roman page numbering

 \include{introduction}
 \include{chapter2}
 \include{chapter3}
 \include{chapter4}
 \include{conclusions}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusions et perspectives}

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{R\'ef\'erences bibliographiques}

 \printbibliography

 %now enable appendix numbering format and include any appendices
 \renewcommand\appendixname{Annexe}
 \appendix
 \include{appendix1}
 \include{appendix2}
 \include{appendix3}
 \include{appendix4}

\include{abstract-eng}      
\include{abstract}          
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you create your bibliography (i.e. which package and style you use: `natbib`, `cite`, `biblatex`, ...)? Please show that in a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/). There are several possible ways to create your bibliography and the solution crucially depends on the package you are using. I'm surprised though that you say that this behaviour came all of a sudden, most bibliography packages have either been stable for years or have had this behaviour consistently for years. So it shouldn't be new.

Comment: I added the mwe, this leads to the bibliography being in smallcaps. As I said, commenting the \usepackage[english,french]{babel} line leads to a normal formatting of the biblography names.

Comment: You must have updated your system if it worked before. Change`\mkbibnamelast` to `\mkbibnamefamily` in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{#1}}`. Or even better, use the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864. For future questions please note that the example as shown now is neither minimal nor working: It is loading many files that we don't have (`BiblioThese.bib` and all the `chapter2` files as well as the relevant `slbiblatex`).

Comment: Perfect ! the \mkbibnamefamily worked ! Sorry about the not so 'we' mwe. I now remember I had to re-download entirely latex a month ago so it might explain the sudden change.

Comment: Indeed, I initially searched for the keyword "smallcaps" which explains why I couldn't find it !