# Apalike style several languages

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, languages, apa-style

I am writting my PhD thesis and I have in the manuscript two version of the introduction: one is in French and the other in English.

I am using the bibliography style apalike.

When using the commands `\cite` of `\citep` in the French part, I would like to have the information in the text in French. For example I have "Author and Author", when I would like to have "Author et Author".

Answer (score 2):

`apalike` is a monolingual style and only speaks English. The "and" you see in the citation is hard-coded and can't be changed easily on the fly (you can edit the `.bst` file to exchange the "and" for something else, even a macro). The styles from the `babelbib` bundle can change the language of the bibliography entries automatically, but the bundle does not come with an equivalent for `apalike`. Some styles such as those of the `harvard` bundle already use a macro for the and (`\harvardand`), which could be redefined when you change languages. But I can't think of a BibTeX style/package that would automatically adapt the citation to the surrounding language.

---

Since you tagged the question with `biblatex`, here is a solution using that package. Note that BibTeX styles such as `apalike` are completely incompatible with `biblatex`, so there is some work involved in switching to `biblatex` and you can not continue to use `apalike`, you'll have to find a different style. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

I'm not aware of a `biblatex` style that would give the exact same output as `apalike`, but you can start from the standard `authoryear` style and modify it as you see fit. There are many questions about that on this site, you can find a good start in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

With `biblatex` citations automatically adapt to the surrounding language and so

```
\documentclass[french,british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\chapter{French}
Bonjour \cite{sigfridsson}
\end{otherlanguage}


\chapter{English}
Hello \cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Bonjour Sigfridsson et Ryde 1998]

[image: Hello Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998]

If you don't like the small caps in the French citations you can disable them with

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```

See also [Keep lowercase in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864).

Comment: This is may not be quite what's needed, since this changes the formatting of the citation to small caps. I would guess that identical formatting might be required.

Comment: @AlanMunn Added a way to get rid of the small caps. Switching to `biblatex` will of course change other aspects of the style as well, so there is still a risk of this not being exactly what was desired.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses `natbib` and a modified version of `apalike.bst`. First, make a copy of `apalike.bst` and put it in the same folder as your thesis file. In this example, I'll name the file `apalike-bilingual`.

In it you will find two functions:

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
```

and

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
```

In each of these functions you will find code that contains `" and "`.  This is the code you will change. In the `format.lab.names` change:

```
{ " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

to

```
{ " \harvardand\ " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

In principle, this is the only thing you need to do, since you just want citation callouts to change. But for completeness, you also want to change the `label-names` function. Change:

```
{ " and " * t * }
```

to

```
{ " \harvardand\ " * t * }
```

What this does now makes a version of `apalike` that uses the `\harvardand` macro for its `and`.  Note that the following `\` in the changed code is important, since spaces get gobbled after a macro.

Using the solution that Ulrike Fischer provided here: [language dependent citations and natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482496/2693) we can now make the `\harvardand` command sensitive to the current `babel`language by adding the French version of `\harvardand` to `\frenchcaptions`. Thanks to Ulrike for this solution and to moewe for pointing out that we can use `babel` directly instead of using a conditional as in the linked question.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{twoauthors,
title={A cool paper},
author={Duck, A. and Marmot, A.},
journal={Journal of Irrelevant Science},
year={2019},
volume={1}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-bilingual}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\harvardand}{and}
\appto\captionsfrench{\DeclareRobustCommand{\harvardand}{et}}

\begin{document}


English citation: \cite{twoauthors}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
French citation: \cite{twoauthors}
\end{otherlanguage}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: You could also use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\harvardand}{and}
\appto\captionsfrench{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\harvardand}{et}%
}` and get rid of `iflang`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I've updated the answer; it's a cleaner solution.