# language dependent citations and natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, tex-core, babel, auxiliary-files

This is a question about how BibTeX and TeX interact.

In this question: [Apalike style several languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482439/2693) the OP asks for a way to get citation callouts with French in one part of the document, and English in the other part of the document. A `biblatex` solution is suggested, which of course works, but doesn't use `natbib` anymore.

I'm not trying to solve this problem directly, but instead trying to understand why it is that the following simple minded approach to the problem won't work.  The approach simply makes the `natbib` `\harvardand` macro a conditional that checks for the current language, and inserts the appropriate word.   I assume the problem is that at the point that `\harvardand` is expanded, the language name is unavailable. I'd like to understand the details of how this works, and if there's a way to do this at all  using an approach along these lines.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{twoauthors,
title={A cool paper},
author={Duck, A. and Marmot, A.},
journal={Journal of Irrelevant Science},
year={2019},
volume={1}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\gdef\harvardand{\IfLanguageName{french}{et}{and}}}
\begin{document}
\cite{twoauthors} Manually: {Duck \harvardand\ Marmot}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\cite{twoauthors} Manually: {Duck \harvardand\ Marmot}
\end{otherlanguage}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: where is the bib style from?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry that was left over from my testing. I've changed the code to use a standard one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the command robust (so that it survives the travel throught the aux-file), and you should redefine it after \begin{document}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\harvardand}{\IfLanguageName{french}{et}{and}}

\cite{twoauthors} Manually: {Duck \harvardand\ Marmot}

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\cite{twoauthors} Manually: {Duck \harvardand\ Marmot}
\end{otherlanguage}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The difference between the robust definition and the \gdef can be seen in the aux-file:

```
\bibcite{twoauthors}{{1}{2019}{{Duck \harvardand  \ Marmot}}{{}}}

\bibcite{twoauthors}{{1}{2019}{{Duck and\ Marmot}}{{}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. Could you possibly add a bit of explanation as to why this solution works (since my question is really about why the simple solution doesn't work.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I added a short comment.

Comment: I hope "Duck and Marmot" is only because in the field they insist on alphabetic ordering. ;-)

Comment: Thank yo very much. For some reason I cannot compile my file when using `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}', I can only compile with the english option. Would it be possible to have a solution not based on language but based on chapter? I.e. if chapter X, use "**et**", and for any other chapter, use "**and**". Thanks a lot.