# Changing bibliography style for one chapter

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, languages

I have one chapter in my latex report which is in French (the other chapters are in English).

I use natbib to generate the bibliography and the citations have the following format when having two authors: Author1  and Author2 (1997).

The issue is that I would like to the change the "**and**" with "**et**" (i.e. the French equivalent) in the French chapter, while keeping "**and**" in the other chapters.

Is it possible to modify citations format for one chapter only? I use the same .bib file for the whole report.

**EDIT**: I have in the preamble the command `AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{and}}`. So the idea would be to have `\renewcommand{\harvardand}{et}}` just before the French chapter. However this modifies the whole document, not only the French section. Maybe something can be done by using `\ifcase` in `\renewcommand` but I don't know how.

**EDIT 2**: There is a solution described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482496/language-dependent-citations-and-natbib), using the command `\DeclareRobustCommand{\harvardand}{\IfLanguageName{french}{et}{and}}` but for some reason I cannot compile my file using `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}`. How could I do something similar but instead of `IfLanguageName`, have something like "IfChapter...etc..."

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If I understand your document setup correctly, you have separate bibliographies for each chapter. Please tell us more about how you create these separate bibliographies. In particular, do please indicate which document class and which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Hi, thanks. No, I have a single bibliography file which is called at the end of the report using \\bibliography{References}. I use natbib and \bibliographystyle{agsm}. The document class is {report}. I hope this is the information you were asking for.