Convert all Uppercase first and last name into Lowercase excepted for the first letter of first and last name
Once lcompilation acheived, I have the following result :

as you can see, all the first/last names are in Uppercase.
However, I use the follwoing bibliography :
@article{book:1,
    author = "W. McCrea",
    title = "Newtonian Cosmology",
    journal = "Nature",
    volume = "175",
    pages = "466",
    year = "1955"
}

@article{book:2,
    author = "A. R. Thatcher",
    title = "Newtonian cosmology and Friedmann's equation",
    journal = "Eur. J. Phys.",
    volume = "3",
    pages = "202",
    year = "1982"
}

@article{book:3,
    author = "J. D. Barrow",
    title = "Non-Euclidean Newtonian Cosmology",
    journal = "Classical and Quantum Gravity",
    volume = "37",
    pages = "125007",
    year = "2020"
}

@book{book:4,
    author = "A. Liddle",
    title = "An Introduction to Modern Cosmology",
    edition = "3",
    publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons",
    year = "2015"
}

@book{book:5,
    author = "B. Ryden",
    title = "Introduction to Cosmology",
    edition = "2",
    publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
    year = "2016"
}

@book{book:6,
    author = "S. Weinberg",
    title = "Cosmology",
    publisher = "Oxford University Press",
    year = "2008"
}

@book{book:7,
    author = "S. Dodelson and F. Schmidt",
    title = "Modern Cosmology",
    edition = "2",
    publisher = "Elsevier Science",
    year = "2020"
}

@article{book:8,
    author = "P. Lemos, A. Lewis",
    title = "CMB constraints on the early universe independent of late time cosmology",
    eprint = "2302.12911",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "astro-ph.CO",
    year = "2023"
}

@article{book:9,
    author = "C. Umilta, J. F. Cardoso, K. Benabed, M. Le Jeune",
    title = "The CMB angular power spectrum via component separation: a study on Planck data",
    journal = "A \& A",
    volume = "624",
    pages = "A67",
    year = "2019"
}

@article{book:10,
    author = "A. Maniyar, G. Lagache, M. Béthermin, S. Ilic",
    title = "Constraining cosmology with the cosmic microwave and infrared backgrounds correlation",
    journal = "A \& A",
    volume = "621",
    pages = "A32",
    year = "2019"
}

@article{book:11,
    author = "G. E. Addison, G. Hinshaw, M. Halpern, and others",
    title = "Cosmological constraints from baryon acoustic oscillations and clustering of large-scale structure",
    journal = "Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society",
    volume = "436",
    issue = "2",
    pages = "1674–1683",
    year = "2013"
}

@article{book:12,
    author = "J. L. Bernal, T. L. Smith, K. K. Boddy, M. Kamionkowski",
    title = "Robustness of baryon acoustic oscillation constraints for early-universe modifications to \(\Lambda\)CDM",
    journal = "Phys. Rev. D",
    volume = "102",
    pages = "123515",
    year = "2020"
}

@article{book:13,
    author = "X. Zhang, Qing-Guo Huang",
    title = "Commun. Theor. Phys.",
    volume = "71",
    pages = "826",
    year = "2019"
}

@article{book:14,
    author = "W. E. Ballinger, J. A. Peacock, A. F. Heavens",
    title = "Measuring the cosmological constant with redshift surveys",
    journal = "Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society",
    volume = "282",
    pages = "877",
    year = "1996"
}

@article{book:15,
    author = "C. L. Bennett et al.",
    title = "The Microwave Anisotropy Probe (MAP) Mission",
    journal = "ApJ",
    volume = "583",
    issue = "1",
    pages = "1–23",
    year = "2003"
}

As you can see, the bibiliography is well written wit a first Uppercase for first and last names and Lowercase for the rest of first and last names.
The order is not the same since I think that I have used in main.tex, i.e this :
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\usepackage[ED=SDU2E-Ast, Ets=UT3]{tlsflyleaf} % Packaged to generate the first page

How to fix this issue of first/last names in full  Uppercase ?
ps: you will that "ET AL." is also in Uppercase at some points.

authors should be separated by and, so "P. Lemos, A. Lewis" should be "P. Lemos and A. Lewis", and similar for the next books. Apart from this: you don't have uppercase but small caps.

Actually, [8] appears to be both lower case (first and third names) and small caps (second  name).

They are not in upper case. That is small-caps and it is presumably a setting in the bibliography style you're using.

Without an example document that we can compile and investigate it is hard to say for sure, but this looks as though your document is in French, in which case biblatex uses small caps for family names. You can disable that as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864.

Note that author = "C. L. Bennett et al.", should be author = "C. L. Bennett and others", (regardless of the exact output you want "et al." to produce you need to use the special keyword and others in the input). And as Ulrike already said, author = "W. E. Ballinger, J. A. Peacock, A. F. Heavens", is also wrong, it should be author = "W. E. Ballinger and J. A. Peacock and A. F. Heavens", etc. etc. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864
